# Redirect simple HTML page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am performing JavaScript validation on a simple HTML page. On error I am trying to redirect the page to Error.html, using `window.location.href="Error.html"`.

I get the JavaScript pop displaying the error but page doesn't redirect.

**JS:**

```
function checkifFormIsFilled() {

    var txtUserName = document.getElementById("txtUserName").value;
    var txtFirstName = document.getElementById("txtFirstName").value;
    var txtLastName = document.getElementById("txtLastName").value;
    var txtEmail = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;
    var txtArea = document.getElementById("txtArea").value;

    var errMessage = "";
    var errorInForm = false;

    if (txtUserName === "") {
        errMessage = "UserName";
        errorInForm = true;
    }
    if (txtFirstName === "") {
        errMessage += ", First Name";
        errorInForm = true;
    }
    if (txtLastName === "") {
        errMessage += ", Last Name";
        errorInForm = true;
    }
    if (txtEmail === "") {
        errMessage += ", Email";
        errorInForm = true;
    }
    if (txtArea === "") {
        errMessage += ", Address";
        errorInForm = true;
    }


    if (errorInForm == true) {
        errMessage += " are required fields";
        window.alert(errMessage);
        //window.location.href = "Error.html";        
        window.navigate("Error.html");
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" style="width: 560px; height: 850px; margin-left: 10px; margin-top:10px">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New User</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>User Name:</label></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtUserName" name="User Name" onblur="checkRequired(this)" maxlength="10" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>First Name:</label></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtFirstName" name="First Name" maxlength="10" onblur="checkRequired(this)" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Last Name:</label></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtLastName" name="Last Name" maxlength="10" onblur="checkRequired(this)" /></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Email: </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="emailInput" id="txtEmail" onblur="checkRequired(this)" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td>
                    <label for="lblAddress">Address</label></td>
                <td>
                    <textarea id="txtArea" name="txtAddress" cols="50" rows="5" maxlength="1000" onblur="checkRequired(this)"></textarea></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>Groups</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="selGroups">
                        <option value="c1">Employee</option>
                        <option value="c1">HR</option>
                        <option value="c1">Director</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Status</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="selStatus">
                        <option value="c1">Active</option>
                        <option value="c2">Inactive</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="btnSubmit" value="Add User" type="submit" onclick="checkifFormIsFilled();" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button id="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: @qwerty You probably put the function definition in page load

Comment: Put the function call in an `onsubmit` attribute on the form instead. You may also have to `return false` as well.

Comment: An error redirecting to an error page. Oh the irony!.

Comment: Also, just a note on user experience, I, as the user, would appreciate you much more if you'd state where the error is inline, rather than throwing me away on some error page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the function call in an `onsubmit` attribute on the `form` element instead. You may also have to return false as well, if an error was found, to prevent it from going to the same page instead of your error page.

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
  if (errorInForm == true) {
            errMessage += " are required fields";
            window.alert(errMessage);
            window.location = "Error.html";
        }
```

Comment: That is actually less semantic than window.location.href and achieves the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input id="btnSubmit" value="Add User" type="button" onclick="checkifFormIsFilled();" />
```

Since the form was submitting to itself, the redirect wasn't occurring.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4VwFP/6/)

Comment: I had specified `action="SomeOtherPage.html"` in form tag, but still was not able to redirect using JS.

Comment: @ankit If you do that it will redirect to SomeOtherPage instead of Error.html. Check the demo.